# Can we publish an existing github repo as nuget package?

Tags: .net, nuget-package, asp.net-core-1.1

I would like to use this library:

https://github.com/geeklearningio/PushSharp-Core

But I have no idea how turn this into nuget package or to include it in my existing .NET Core 1.1 app. I need to version specifically.

Comment: It already has a nuget package, do you see the badge on github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That package already exists on nuget, https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushSharp

But otherwise you could use appveyor to do what you're asking https://www.appveyor.com/docs/nuget/

EDIT: If you don't own the github project/fork, you can fork it yourself and then use appveyor to create a nuget package from that.

Otherwise you can create your own nuget package manually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

Comment: Jim, that's the original version. The one I linked to is a forked version that has been converted to work with net core 1.0

Is there any alternatives to nuget that would allow me to use that version?

Comment: @user6728767 if it helped you should mark this as an answer, thanks.

Comment: Okay I will. I thought an update was coming so I was waiting for your followup.

Comment: Thanks, I already wrote it, see "EDIT:", let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to just add that as a refernece in my csproj file instead using <ItemGroup> somehow? I'm new to .net so not quite sure how that works.

Comment: @user6728767 I see, you can either i) download the project from GitHub, and add that project to your solution - from there you can reference that project from your user project, or ii) you can download the project, build it in VS and then reference the output DLL in your main project.

Comment: If I use option ii, would I only need to locate the DLL file and put it in my directory, or would I sitll have to bring the entire project in too?

Comment: @user6728767 reference the DLL directly from the output of the PushSharp-Core bin/release folder.  Then when you build your project that DLL will be included in your bin folder, and you can deploy it as-is.  No need to include the entire PushSharp-Core project.

Comment: Ahh okay. In that directory, there seems t be other DLL files as well. Are those just dependencies that PushSharp requires? Do I need to drag those over as well.

Comment: Is this the right way to do it : `<Reference Include="PushSharp">
      <HintPath>Libraries\PushSharp.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>`

Comment: You'll want to reference all of PushSharps dependencies as well, and yes the snippet is good.

Comment: So when I do a put request to my controller that uses PushSharp it crashes with: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly` at the line where I do : `Using PushSharp`. The weird thing is my editor doesn't complain about anything and I can also right click to see the implementation details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169119/discussion-between-jim-w-and-user6728767).